# Should the odds ratio be used to judge incremental information in psychological scales?

Tags: ratio, odds

I am looking at the incremental validity of the MMPI-A-RF (a psychological instrument) and MACI (another psychological instrument) in the prediction of the DSM code for depression disorders found in the clinical record prior to testing. Both psychological instruments are continuous variables, and the outcome variable (DSM code) is dichotomous (DSM depression diagnosis present: (yes/no)).

How do you apply an odds ratio to determine the effect size in this example? Should I apply the odds ratio in this case? I have eight, continuous predictors in total.